# ¿Cómo extraigo la parte entera de un número decimal en Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, float, números-enteros

Estoy configurando un Script en BASH para que levante datos de una BASE.

Funciona bien, solo que cuando tiene que comparar valores en DECIMALES me toma como estado "UNKNOWN" el resultado. Y si es un número ENTERO me da estado "OK".

Detalló el script para ver si me pueden ayudar y unas imagenes. La idea es que si puedo dar un rango de valores enteros ejemplo = "26" y me devuelve el resultado "26.04" , no tome el ".04" como un dato válido , sino que lo pase por alto y solo tome como válido el número "26" y que descarte los decimales , que los muestre pero que a la hora de verificar los descarte.

```
#!/bin/bash

host="x.x.x.x"
usuario="x.x.x.x"
password="x.x.x.x"
database="x.x.x.x"
sql="-h $host -u $usuario -p$password -D $database -s -e"
valor=$(mysql $sql "SELECT sensor1 FROM log where id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM 
log);")

load=$(echo $valor)
loadok=$(echo $valor)
loadw1=$(echo $valor)
loadw2=$(echo $valor)
loadw3=$(echo $valor)
loadc=$(echo $valor)

vok="15"
vwar1="27"
vwar2="28"
vwar3="29"
vcri="30"

output="Temperatura Sensor: $load C" 

if [ $loadok -le $vok ]
then
  echo "OK- $output"
  exit 0
elif [ $loadw1 -eq $vwar1 ]
then
  echo "WARNING- $output"
  exit 1
elif [ $loadw2 -eq $vwar2 ]
then
  echo "WARNING- $output"
  exit 1
elif [ $loadw3 -eq $vwar3 ]
then
  echo "WARNING- $output"
  exit 1
elif [ $loadc -ge $vcri ]
then
  echo "CRITICAL- $output"
  exit 2
else
echo "UNKNOWN- $output"
exit 3
fi
```

[image: Como se puede Observar en la imagen, si detecta un valor con "Decimales" , se pone en estado "UNKNOWN" , de lo contrario , si detecta un Valor "Entero" se pone en estado "OK"]

Comment: Dado `var=1.23`, puedes hacer `int=${var%.*}` para quedarte con la parte entera (esto no redondea, solo trunca).

Comment: Buenas noches , muchas gracias , ya lo pude solucionar de Esa manera , mil gracias por tu ayuda,  saludos.

Comment: Vale. Añadí una respuesta, dale a aceptar si te resolvió el problema! Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es conseguir la parte entera de un número con parte decimal, puedes decir:

```
var=1.23
parte_entera=${var%.*}
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ var=1.23
$ echo "${var%.*}"
1
```